# mute timeline sounds if swf is not visible

Tags: flash, mute

I have sounds in the timeline of an animation and my swf is above the fold (in a very high html page) I would like to mute everything if the user scrolls down beyond the swf on the page. Does anybody know *IF* and *HOW* this can be done?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. In Javascript you would listen for the "onscroll" event to detect when the Flash element is is no longer on the page. Then via Flash's ExternalInterface class, Javascript can tell Flash to mute the sound.

Comment: @SunilD what if the user has javascript disabled?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c36cfb8137124318eebc6-8000.html

If you have your publish settings set to Flash Player 10.1 or higher, you can easily stop the audio/video:

Flash Player 10.1 enhancements for CPU usage

Flash Player 10.1 introduces two new features that help save CPU processing. The features involve pausing and resuming SWF content when it goes offscreen, and limiting the number of Flash Player instances on a page.

Pause, throttle, and resume

Note: The pause, throttle, and resume feature does not apply to Adobe® AIR® applications.
To optimize CPU and battery usage, Flash Player 10.1 introduces a new feature on related to inactive instances. This feature allows you to limit CPU usage by pausing and resuming the SWF file when content goes off and on the screen. With this feature, Flash Player releases as much memory as possible by removing any objects that can be recreated when the playing of content is resumed. Content is considered offscreen when the entire content is offscreen.

Two scenarios cause the SWF content to be offscreen:

**It is clearly stated here:****

***The user scrolls the page and causes the SWF content to move offscreen.
In this case, if there is any audio or video playback, content continues to play, but rendering is stopped. If there is no audio or video playing, to ensure that the playback or ActionScript execution is not paused, set the hasPriority HTML parameter to true. However, keep in mind that SWF content rendering is paused when content is offscreen or hidden, regardless of the value of the hasPriority HTML parameter.***

A tab is opened in the browser, which causes the SWF content to move to the background.
In this case, regardless of the value of the hasPriority HTML tag, the SWF content is slowed down, or throttled, to between 2 and 8 fps. Audio and video playback is stopped and no content rendering is processed unless the SWF content becomes visible again.
For Flash Player 11.2 and later running on Windows and Mac desktop browsers, you can use the ThrottleEvent in your application. Flash Player dispatches a ThrottleEvent when Flash Player pauses, throttles, or resumes play.

The ThrottleEvent is a broadcast event, which means that it is dispatched by all EventDispatcher objects with a listener registered for this event. For more information about broadcast events, see the DisplayObject class.